# arranging files in a folder according to another folder

Tags: file-management

I've 2 folders. Folder 1 has some files arranged in some sub folders. Folder 2 has same-filenamed-files (but different size) but not arranged in any sub folder. I want to arrange folder 2 files like folder 1. Is there a quick way to do that? I'm using Linux.

Comment: There's no existing tool to do what you want.  You'll have to write a script.  Hint: a simple algorithm to do this is to iterate through the sub-directories of Folder1 and, for each sub-directory: 1.  create the same subdir in Folder2; 2. get the list of filenames in the sub-dir 3. move the same filenames in Folder2 to Folder2/subdir.       **Write your script as a dry-run (i.e. only print what it would do) until you're sure it's going to work correctly.**   If you write it in shell, remember to double-quote your variables.

Comment: Does your system offer the `tree` command?

Comment: yes, using Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Mayhap something along these lines will do:

```
cd "$folder1"
echo "mkdir -p " $(find . -type d | tee /tmp/dirs) > /tmp/tmpscript
find . | awk -F"/" 'FNR == NR {DIR[$0]; next} !($0 in DIR) && !(NF == 2) {print "cp \"" $NF "\" \"" $0"\""}' /tmp/dirs - >> /tmp/tmpscript
cd "$folder2"
less /tmp/tmpscript
# rm /tmp/dirs /tmp/tmpscript
```

It creates a temporary script that first creates the subdirectory structure under folder2, then `cp`s every single file from there into its pertaining subdir. Change `cp` to `mv` if need be. Scrutinize the `tmpscript` first (with e.g. `less`) before actually running it. As a last step, the temp files should be removed. No effort has been done to optimize the copying action; every single file is handled on its own. Improvements could be done like collecting all files bound to one subdir into one copy command.